# Error in calling method from another class when using delegates

Tags: swift

I have tried to run Second ViewController to change appearance on my first ViewController and progressBar(Progress View) cause error, but if I try to call method keyButtonResponse() from First View Controller error doesn`t appear

First ViewController:

```
   import UIKit
   import AVFoundation
   import UserNotifications

   protocol SomeDelegate {
      func keyButtonResponse()
   }

   class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SomeDelegate{


      @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!


      func keyButtonResponse(){
          //some code
          progressBar.progress = 0.01 //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
    }
   }
```

Second ViewController:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: SomeDelegate?
    func keyButtonResponse(){
        delegate?.keyButtonResponse()
    }


    @IBAction func leftButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let myVar = WarningViewController()
        let viewController = ViewController()
        myVar.delegate = viewController
        myVar.keyButtonResponse()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the delegate to an instance of a view controller that's unrelated to `FirstViewController` here.

```swift
let viewController = ViewController()
myVar.delegate = viewController
```

You need to set the delegate to the existing instance of `FirstViewController`.

If you're using a segue:

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? SecondViewController, segue.identifier == "firstVCToSecondVCSegue" {
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

or

```swift
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController {
    vc.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

This should be placed within `FirstViewController`, not `SecondViewController`.